# Uncompressed vs Subdivided: which one offers better PostGIS INTERSECTS performance?

Tags: postgis, point-in-polygon, st-intersects

In my PostGIS I have a point table (roughly 51 millions rows) and a multipolygon table. I need to find a polygon label/ID for every single point in my point table (roughly 51 millions rows) in PostGIS.  So this is considered as point-in-polygon query (with ST_INTERSECTS).

[This](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2018/09/postgis-external-storage.html) article suggests that using external storage for geometries significantly improves point-in-polygon queries. Here, geometries in external storage are not compressed hence the performance improvement; but there's potential extra storage size penalty (which is acceptable).

Another way to improve such query is using ST_SUBDIVIDE as explained [here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html). This way, the polygons are divided into rectangular pieces. Point-in-polygon queries, both *hit* and *miss*, are improved.

Question:

1. Uncompressed vs Subdivided, generally which one is more preferable in terms of performance?
2. If this is rather case-specific, what are the considerations?

Yes I can implement both in a polygon (or multipolygon) table. But when I choose to use small number for *max_vertices* (a param in ST_SUBDIVIDE), the geometries won't be big enough to bleed to be uncompressed.

**Additional infos**

polygon complexity:

- count    =   319 rows
- min      =   97 vertex
- median   =   3,942 vertex
- max      =   217,436 vertex
- stdev    =   22,921.20793 vertex
- average  =   10,458.48903 vertex
- 37 out of 319 have Npoints < 512, so these won't be toasted.

So i made a test using 4 variations for the polygon table:

1. Conventional
2. Uncompressed (but not subdivided)
3. Subdivided (with max vertice= 64, the 319 explodes to 109,574 rows )
4. Subdivided (with max vertice= 512, the 319 explodes to 19,512 rows )

I tested EXPLAIN ANALYZE with a portion (±500k rows) of my point table (total 51 millions of rows) against those 4 variations. This is to get the 'Execution time'.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH poi AS (
SELECT  id, geom 
FROM    point
WHERE   kpr_id = '430' 
)
SELECT  p.id, b.id_polygon
FROM    poi p, polygon b
WHERE   ST_INTERSECTS(b.geom, p.geom) --both geom are indexed
        IS TRUE;
```

Interestingly, their Execution time are:

1. Conventional: 9 minutes
2. Uncompressed (but not subdivided) : 10 minutes
3. Subdivided (with max vertice= 64) : 8.9 hours (!)
4. Subdivided (with max vertice= 512) : 1.7 hours

So it seems that using external (to get uncompressed geometry) does not improve performance. ST_Subdivide even gets worse execution time.

Below is the Explain analyze result (with polygon variation #3, subdivided):

```
Nested Loop  (cost=467106.10..15291893745.32 rows=18183694 width=15) (actual time=8217729.613..32306920.503 rows=526095 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (((b.geom && p.geom) AND _st_intersects(b.geom, p.geom)) IS TRUE)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 57645807435
  CTE poi
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on point  (cost=5958.78..467106.10 rows=497847 width=36) (actual time=587.892..14814.902 rows=526095 loops=1)
          Recheck Cond: ((kpr_id)::text = '430'::text)
          Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1942446
          Heap Blocks: exact=105737 lossy=67782
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on point_kpr_id_idx  (cost=0.00..5834.32 rows=497847 width=0) (actual time=547.728..547.728 rows=526095 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ((kpr_id)::text = '4303130000'::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on polygon b  (cost=0.00..11434.74 rows=109574 width=594) (actual time=5.819..1415.867 rows=109574 loops=1)
  ->  CTE Scan on poi p  (cost=0.00..9956.94 rows=497847 width=36) (actual time=0.016..97.227 rows=526095 loops=109574)
Planning time: 0.415 ms
Execution time: 32306984.195 ms --this is 8,9 hours(!)
```

And below is all Execution time for all 4 polygon variations with each CTE and non-CTE queries.
[image]

Comment: Interesting question and thanks for bringing the EXTERNAL key word to my attention. I think this is one of the cases where the best approach will depend so much on one's use case. For point in polygon, it is easy to see how ST_Subdivide could speed things up, but for polygon/polygon intersection, it might even take longer. As for EXTERNAL, have you checked how many of your polygons are too big and need to be toasted?  I often have to run queries that can take days, intersections of millions of rows vs millions of rows, and I would definitely happy use more space to save time.

Comment: How complicated your polygons are? Do they have tens or tens of thousands vertices?

Comment: Well, more to the point, is ST_NPoints(geom) > 512, as this is the point where TOAST comes into play.

Comment: @user30184, The polygons vary in terms of vertices number. I added polygon complexity numbers in my question

Comment: @JohnPowell, For most of the rows yes (> 512).  I added polygon complexity numbers in my question

Comment: I added my four observation of execution time in my question above. Uncompressed and Subdivided does not improve performance. Did i miss something here? But by the way I also tried the example and dataset provided by Paul Ramsay (in the link in my question), and I confirm that the uncompressed geometry offers 5x faster time. Is there any hidden conditions need to be fulfilled to get the full benefit of external/uncompressed geometry?

Comment: I would say that ST_Subdivide should help and because it does not seem to do it you may do some part of the analysis in sub.optimal way. Compare your workflow and results with this SpatiaLite document http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA1/WorldBorders.pdf.

Comment: To be clear, you created a new column with ST_Subdivide(geom) and spatially indexed it, because your numbers make little sense. I can imagine plenty of situations where ST_Subdivide would not make much difference (as well as costing time and space in its own right), but once in place, it is hard to see how it could perform an order of magnitude worse than your "conventional" case.

Comment: @JohnPowell  Pardon me in case I misunderstand your comment . But if you asked me whether I indexed the geometry column: yes I indexed the subdivided result. And actually i did not just make new column but instead create a new (derivative) table. In the above 4 variations: table #2 #3 #4 are all derived from #1 (conventional). And howelse I can have the subdivided geometry other than by new table, as the original geometries are subdivided into smaller pieces and each piece translates as one row.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for pointing out that article. It stresses that SQL optimization is not enough and understanding to data is vital. It even mentioned that the required geometry simplification is not as what ST_Simplify does  :) . And on a side note, I think the simplification done in the article is by intersecting world boundary with regular square/grid and this is unlike PostGIS ST_Subdivide; although the desired effects are the same. And compared to what i do, there's 2 difference: the article uses 1 point and regular grid intersection, while mine has ±500k points and PostGIS' ST_Subdivide.

Comment: I really believe that Subdivision will improve intersection query, but unfortunately what i did does not prove it. So is there any -undocumented- optimal setting of max vertex? Or any other considerations/ prerequisite ?

Comment: Could you add the SQL that you are using?

Comment: @user30184 Sure, the SQL was added

Comment: Do you have have spatial index in all tables? Could you show the whole execution plan?

Comment: @user30184 Yes both (point and polygon) table are spatial indexed. Result of explain analyze was added. Am glad you ask this.

Comment: Try without a CTE but a regular join on the point table. CTE are an optimization fence (no index will be used once the CTE content has been retrieved).

Comment: @JGH, I just posted a table showing all execution time of all 4 polygon variations each with CTE and non-CTE. Is shows that the Conventional prevails as winner.

Comment: @JGH, I updated my table with the execution time for subdivided Polygon (with max vertice=64), the one with worst execution time. It seems that using non-CTE improves slightly. But again, the conventional polygon wins afterall.